# How can I test my app for a specific device?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am building an application with React Native but the app not working well on a few android devices. So I need to see what's going wrong but I don't know how to set up an emulator for a specific device. Are these problems depends on phone's brand and model or it just depends on their android versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really possible.  There's two major problems:

1. Software.  Real devices don't ship pure AOSP like runs on the emulator.  They add patches and features and there's no way to know what they actually run.
2. Custom UIs.  Many phones provide custom UIs like TouchWhiz and the like which can override Android behavior
3. Hardware.  If your app depends on things that are very hardware specific, like GPS or Camera, they could have issues due to hardware bugs.

If you just want to emulate a specific OS version like KitKat, or specific low memory conditions its possible via emulator configuration.  If you really need to test on a device, either buy one or use a service that allows you remote control over specific devices.  Amazon has a nice device farm that you can rent over AWS.

Comment: I think my problem is about hardware. You helped me a lot to understand the logic. Also thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest challenges when developing for Android is the wide variety of devices and "optimizations" manufacturers make to their Android versions.

The Android emulator is based on AOSP (vanilla Android) and was only recently published with Google services included. This is the most clean version of Android. You can use the emulator to test UI scaling for different screen sizes but it will always behave like an AOSP Android. Google packs a bunch of hardware configurations into Android Studio which you can simply select when creating an virtual device. You can always create a custom hardware profile with custom screen size and resolution. Some manufacturers also change the DPI value of the OS causing the UI to be bigger or smaller, keep this in mind when creating a custom hardware configuration.

Further, you can use the emulator to test the default behaviour on different Android versions. Again, manufacturers change their Android usually causing slightly different behaviour.

I assume that your question is focussed on different behaviour of e.g. Samsung phones having crashes only occuring in Samsung phones (Samsung can be exchanged with any other brand here). Unfortunately, there is no simple way to test this but getting your hands on the faulty device. One option is to use a cloud based test lab (e.g. Firebase Test Lab, App Center or AWS device farm) to test your code on the faulty device or rent the device at a local shop. Most bigger cities have companies renting phones and tablets on a daily or weekly basis.

In the end you will need if statements checking for a specific device, manufacturer or Android version or any combination of them and doing something slightly different to fix the undesired behaviour.

I know that this is not the answer you are looking for, but it's the best I can offer. To tell a little tale of my worst experience: I had once a bug were calling a crypto function caused a kernel panic on HTC (?) phones. This means the user opened my app and the phone rebooted. I was required to implement the entire encryption logic again just for HTC with Android 6.0.